# Lint warning about string comparison in android java

Tags: java, android

I know in java we are supposed to use String.equals to compare the value of two string objects. However, I've been a C++ programmer for too long to remember  that we can't use "==" to compare two strings. I keep making the same mistakes again, again and again.

I guess we couldn't overload an operator like the way we do in C++. I am developing android apps in eclipse. Is there anyway to create a lint rule to at least throw a warning when I attempt to use "==" to compare two Strings?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studio, open the Preferences dialog, select Inspections, and search for "==". You will see a number of "Probable bugs" that you can checkmark.  By the way, the option for Object comparisons does not cover Number or String comparisons.

[image]

Comment: in android 2.2 this setting can be found at `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections`